# excel vba - add table column with date based on adjacent cell that includes date and time

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, date

I have an excel table ("Table1") with 4 total columns. The 3rd and 4th column contain 'clock in' and 'clock out' information formatted to show date and time. For example :

```
 6/3/2016 10:54:52 AM
```

I would like to do two things here...first, I want to create a new, 3rd column that just reads the date, formatted "d-mmm". This should match the date found in what would now be column 4.

The second thing I would like to do is take the date portion of text out of what would now be columns 4 and 5. So at the end, an example row of data might read as follows (columns 3:5):

```
    C,           D,          E
7-Jun, 10:54:52 AM, 4:59:44 AM
```

Here is what I have so far for code:

```
Sub test()

Dim currentSht As Worksheet
Dim lst As ListObject

Set curretnSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set lst = currentSht.ListObjects("Table1")

lst.ListColumns.Add Position:=3
'Not really sure how to do the rest
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the Excel way.  Dates are numbers 0 represents 1/1/1900. Add 1 to it and you get the next day the value of an hour is 1/24 . 
The biggest problem of your approach is Excel you stop editing the cell Excel evaluate the cells value.  It'll still look like 7 - Jun but Excel changes the cells format and the cells value to be 7 - Jun of this your 6/7/216.  It's best to have all the cells equal the same date.  Just change the cells formatting to display the results that you want.  If  you need to calculate the Month use the a WorkSheet Function to do so. =Month(A1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Demo()
    Range("C1").EntireColumn.Insert               '-->insert column
    Range("D:D").Copy Destination:=Range("C1")    '-->copy column 4 to column 3
    Range("C:C").NumberFormat = "d-mmm"           '-->format column 3
    Range("D:E").NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"   '-->format column 4 and 5
End Sub
```

Even this will work:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim currentSht As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Set currentSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = currentSht.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row          '-->get last row with data
    currentSht.Range("C1").EntireColumn.Insert                         '-->insert column
    currentSht.Range("C1:C" & lastRow) = currentSht.Range("D1:D" & lastRow).Value '-->copy column 4 to column 3
    currentSht.Range("C1:C" & lastRow).NumberFormat = "d-mmm"          '-->format column 3
    currentSht.Range("D1:E" & lastRow).NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"  '-->format column 4 and 5
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This meets your specs:

```
Sub InsertColumnAndFormatDates()
    Columns("C:C").Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Columns("C").NumberFormat = "d-mmm"
    Columns("D:E").NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"
End Sub
```